# Core Data - check if relationship is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to check if a relationship object in a returned query is nil. When I print the relationship it literally says nil in the log but checking against nil does not work. If I then check against a property in the object I get a crash because that just does not exist in the returned array.

This is out of the log:

```
2015-05-22 10:20:18.458 Test [819:31066] (
"<Days: 0x7f859bfbcc30> (
    entity: Days; 
    id: 0xd0000000002c0004 <x-coredata://FDD2AA25-AC20-4A8F-AF2C-59542B4BBD7B/Days/p11> ; 
    data: {\n    
        date = \"2015-05-22 07:46:30 +0000\";\n    
        formattedDate = \"2015-05-21 22:00:00 +0000\";\n    
        testrelationship = nil;\n
    }
)"
```

And this is how I wanted to check if it's nil.

```
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", results);
Test *test = [results valueForKey:@"quantity"];

if (test.price == nil) {
```

Does anyone know how to check against a relationship object being nil?

Comment: 1 to 1 or 1 to many relationship? What is the crash? Why aren't you using a predicate to filter the result returned from the fetch?

Comment: 2015-05-22 10:34:20.167 Test [884:34572] -[__NSArrayI price]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa587f0750
2015-05-22 10:34:20.169 Test [884:34572] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI price]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa587f0750'

Comment: I use a predicate but I use it to check for a day which has the testrelationship object in it. It might happen that I create the day but there wont be anything to add for that testrelationship. I know what to add something if there isn't anything and if there is something already I want to add the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
Test *test = [results valueForKey:@"quantity"];
```

isn't doing what you expect, because calling `valueForKey` on an array returns an array, not a `Test` object. So `test.price` is trying to access a property on an array that obviously doesn't exist.

You probably want something like:

```
Test *test = [results firstObject];
```

(but I can't tell why you're using `quantity`).

Comment: `quantity` is a property in the Test entity